# Ant build with Eclipse Mars fails due to missing classpath reference

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classpath

I recently moved to Eclipse Mars and installed JDK 8u51. I'm using the JBoss Tools plugin with my Eclipse and have a couple of Ant files to build my projects.

When I double-click on a build file in the Ant view, however, my project won't built. Instead I get this error message:

```
The archive: C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Eclipse%20Mars/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150528-0211.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

I checked the file system and the JAR is actually there. Any ideas how I could fix that? Maybe it's the spaces (`%20`) in the path name?

Unfortunately, I don't know where this dependency comes from. In the **External Tools Configuration** it is under **Additional Tasks & Support**, but I cannot edit the entry there. Nor did I find any other dialog where I can actually configure this reference.

Comment: Can you add the relevant portions of your Ant build script?

Comment: The build files simply call a set of Maven targets. There is no reference to the aforementioned JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse 4.5.1 was released on October the 2nd and [Bug 470390](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470390) has been fixed.

The update resolves this issue.

Comment: I just had to circumvent the same misbehavior in Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600 by creating the mklinks.

Answer (score 11):

Having had the exact same issue with Eclipse Mars, it turned out the problem was related to the '%20' stuff and not to the jar in itself.

You can either work on a different folder than "Program Files" (install eclipse somewhere else, ...), or create a symbolic link so that ant can see the existing repository the way it knows it. Run the following command in the elevated command prompt(`Start > Type cmd > Right click and Run as administrator`)

```
mklink /d c:\Program%20Files%20(x86) "c:\Program Files (x86)"
```

(and the same for "Eclipse Mars" directory, that you could also rename to remove the space)

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I found [this bugtracker issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470390) myself. I suppose this is getting fixed soon. As a workaround, I moved my Eclipse to a folder without any spaces.

Comment: Wow, creating Symbolic link using the mklink command with the elevated command prompt worked for me.(updated your answer to include that) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Only need to remove blank spaces in the directory name.